# Copies of Android Studio source files aren't current

Tags: android-studio, zip, backup, project

I tried the simple way to create a backup of my Android Studio project, by creating a Zip file of the project, but the files have much older modification dates. Sure enough, when I open them with a text editor, they don't have the mods I made. What's going on here? When I edit them in Studio, everything is good, but when I copy a file to my Windows 7 desktop, I only get an old version. I suspect that the problem has something to do with Android Studio's source change control system.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the app folder contains a src folder that holds the current source.